# SQL Server 2008 R2: Remove single occurrence record.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with two columns as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_lin
(
    Cola INT,
    Colb INT
);

INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(1,3);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(1,4);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(1,5);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(1,3);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(2,4);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(2,6);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(2,7);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(2,4);
INSERT INTO test_lin VALUES(2,6);
```

**Note**: Now I want to show only those records which are repeated more then once. Like in my case `(1,3),(2,4),(2,6)` records are repeated in the table.

[image]

I want to remove the single occurrence records from the result set. The records which are single occurrence are as shown below in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT Cola,Colb,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cola,Colb ORDER BY Cola) AS RN
FROM test_lin
)

SELECT T.* 
FROM test_lin T INNER JOIN  CTE C ON C.COLa = t.Cola and C.COLb = t.Colb and c.RN=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  WITH cte AS 
 (SELECT cola, colb
  FROM test_lin
  GROUP BY cola, colb
  HAVING count(*) > 1)
  SELECT l.*
  from test_lin l INNER JOIN CTE ON 
       l.cola = cte.cola and l.colb=cte.colb
```

Comment: I want to show repeated records also. Is that possible?

Comment: Didn't know you need the whole record. Dark Knight's answer is obviously accepted but this version would work for you as well.

Comment: Need to remove `DISTINCT` from outer SELECT statement, then the result will be the expected result. Well! Thank you so much. Up vote for sure for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample, I taken from @Ala sample and adding something:

1) First option

```
select * from 
(
 SELECT *
  FROM test_lin
  GROUP BY cola, colb
  HAVING count(*) > 1
  ) cte
join test_lin l  ON 
 l.cola = cte.cola and l.colb=cte.colb
```

2) correction in @Ala answer.

```
;WITH cte AS 
 (SELECT cola, colb
  FROM test_lin
  GROUP BY cola, colb
  HAVING count(*) > 1)
  SELECT  l.*   --remove distinct only
  from test_lin l INNER JOIN CTE ON 
       l.cola = cte.cola and l.colb=cte.colb
```

Comment: Please recheck the result of your script.